# R repeating sequence add 1 each repeat

Tags: r, sequence, repeat, seq, rep

I have a workbook problem for my R class I can't figure out.  I need to "write an R command that uses rep() to create a vector with elements 1 2 3 4 2 3 4 5 3 4 5 6 4 5 6 7"

It seems to be a repeating sequence of 1 to 4, repeating 4 times and on each repeat adding 1 to the starting element.  I'm very very new to R so I'm stumped.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We can use `rep` and add with the initial vector

```
v1 + rep(0:3, each = length(v1))
#[1] 1 2 3 4 2 3 4 5 3 4 5 6 4 5 6 7
```

Or using `sapply`

```
c(sapply(v1, `+`, 0:3))
```

Or using `outer`

```
c(outer(v1, 0:3, `+`))
```

#### data

```
v1 <- 1:4
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use `sequence`:

```r
sequence(rep(4, 4), 1:4)
#[1] 1 2 3 4 2 3 4 5 3 4 5 6 4 5 6 7
```